# Stop, Play, Horisontal Scroll Bar for time

Tags: javascript

[image]I need a way to:

Have a contol that can accept time values 
for example values: 01:15:30, 5:28:45, 16:15:01, 23:44:59

These values need to be loaded into the horisontal 'time-control bar' .  I want to be able to click "play" so it would go through array of locaded time values and generated the event for each "value"

I have never done ths before, so I need some help. I will manage the rest (including values generations and event handling)

Comment: you idea is still in your mind , plz put some more words e.g Do you need GUI handling or Design .Your description is vague

Comment: That is an interesting idea. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did some research and found simiar projects:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/time_sliderwithdynamiclayer/index.html

http://filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using jquery ( if not heavy or extra burden for your project )

Check [jquery time slider](http://akzhan.github.com/jquery-time-slider/)